# Method does not return view after Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net-core, view

I have a `GetPerson` method which returns a `People` view.

```
Public ActionResult GetPerson()
{
      //code shortened for brevity
      return View(people);
}
```

and here's my view

```
@model ModelLayer.Models.NotificationModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Kendo.Mvc
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<div>
 //code shortened for brevity
</div>

$("#customSaveButton").on("click", function () {
        var model = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model?.uploadModels))');
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveFile", "Upload")',
            data: {
                model: model,
                saveType: saveType
            }

        })

    });
```

I get the model from the `People` view and send it to another method `SavePeople` via an ajax call but my `SavePeople` method does not want to return a view because of the ajax call and here's my method

```
public ActionResult SavePeople(List<People> model)
        {
            //code shortened for brevity
            ViewBag.Message = String.Format(cmdMessage);
            return View(tModel);
        }
```

What are my options here? Will using a partial view resolve this? Or should I go with something else?

Comment: Where is your ajax `success: function(response)` to handle the response?

Comment: I have none, could that be the issue? @SowmyadharGourishetty

Comment: Could you add that and try. add `success: function(response) {console.log(response); }` after `data` in your ajax code. what are you trying to achieve? can you please let us know more about your requirement.

Comment: I have a method `GetPerson` which returns a `People` view. Inside that `People` view I get the model and send it to another method, `SavePeople` via the `ajax` call. The method `SavePeople` returns a view called `SavedPeople`. Because of the ajax call, my `SavePeople` method cannot return it's view `SavedPeople`. That's what I want to do, return the `SavePeople` view. @SowmyadharGourishetty

Comment: create the `SavedPeople` view as a partial view and try. but don't forget to add the `success: function()` to your ajax code.

Comment: I tried adding the `success: function()` but not in the partial view. It returned the entire view. HTML & all. @SowmyadharGourishetty

Comment: Yes, now you can use that HTML and append it anywhere in the current page

Comment: sorry but how do I append it? If I understand you correctly, I can append the response to my method? In my method I return a view? How do I append the response to the view?

Comment: see this example https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-Partial-View-from-Controller-using-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx#:~:text=The%20Partial%20View%20will%20be,in%20ASP.Net%20MVC%20Razor.